# What's wrong between my Javascript and PHP communication for uploading an image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was requested to use only Javascript (Ajax/Jquery/JSON) only. Why doesn't this work?

Here's my code that I embedded in HTML script:

```
function uploadImage(){
    $.post("signup/upload.php", function(data)
    {
        if(data['status']!='ok'){
          $("#status").html(data['status']);
          console.log("!Failure");
        }else{
          $('#status').html("Your picture was uploaded!");
          console.log("Success");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#uploadImageButton').on('click', function()
    {
        uploadImage();
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id = "uploadImageButton" name="submit">
```

Here is the PHP:

```
  $reply['status'] = 'ok';
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) {
                    $allowed = array ('image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg','image/JPG');
                    if (in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'], $allowed)) {
                            if (move_uploaded_file
                                    ($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "/fakepath/www/upload_files/{$_FILES['upload']['name']}"))
                            {
                                    $reply['status'] = 'ok';
                                    echo '<p><em>The file has been uploaded!</em></p>';
                            }

                    } else {
                            echo '<p class="error">Please upload a JPEG or PNG image.</p>';
                    }
        }
}
print json_encode($reply);
?>
```

Comment: What about it "doesn't work"? Is the request being made to the server? Is the server responding? Is the image not being saved?

Comment: You need to use FormData API to upload files using ajax or you have to base 64 encode them

Comment: The server is responding but the image is not being saved.

Comment: You're not sending any data to the server in your `$.post()` call.

Comment: @Barmar So how do I do that?

Comment: Read the documentation of `$.post`. The second argument is the `data` to be sent to the server. But you can't use that for file uploads, see the answers in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$.ajax` request, e.g below.

**HTML :**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id = "uploadImageButton" name="submit">
<form>
```

**JS :**

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('submit', 'form', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "signup/upload.php",
            data: new FormData(this),
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //your code
            }
        });

        return false;
    })  
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not that simple and requires different options in `$.ajax`

Comment: Hmm I get "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Comment: note that second version will only send the file name which is what `val()` will return

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl for your intervention, updated my answer.

Comment: _note that second version will only send the file name_ Ok @charlietfl any suggestion?

Comment: yes..need to use FormData APi... and not allow data processing

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl updated my answer please take a look.

Comment: untested but seems about right

Comment: @Dil check my update please.

Comment: I really appreciate the help but still nothing. I still get !Failure.
I embedded all of your code inside "uploadImage();" and removed all of mine.

Comment: @Dil won't ever get past `isset($_POST['submit']`

Comment: @charliefl You're absolutely right. Why though?

Comment: Because we're not sending any parameter called `submit`.

Comment: because it doesn't exist unless you append to data. Also you echo html in one place and json in another. php needs cleaning up

Comment: Yeah the echoing was just for testing purposes. So how do I append it?

Comment: You should remove the `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` condition, and check what will happen.

Comment: There is no difference! This has gotten me stumped.

Comment: Okay i'll test it localy right now, just wait.

Comment: @Dil when you call your JS code (onclick, onsubmit..)?

Comment: On click and thanks by the way for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104583/discussion-between-zakaria-acharki-and-dil).

Answer (score 0):

First PHP instruction `$reply['status'] = 'ok';` would not execute because it is placed before PHP open tag.